# Restrict the Application selected language irrespective of Device selected language

Tags: java, android-studio

How to restrict the device language change in built-in Applications in android ? if Application language is selected as English , even though the device language changed to some other language other than English then also wants to remains my application to be in Application selected language ? How to achieve this ? My Application needs to support multi language.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am using below code to support multiple languages for my App.                      
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);                                                                                       
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        Context appContext = ApplicationClass.getApplicationContext();
        Resources appResources = appContext.getResources();
        appResources.updateConfiguration(config, appResources.getDisplayMetrics());

Comment: can anyone help me to handle multiple language support for my app